# Multiple setonInfoWindowClickListener not working

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

So these are my two loops in the map and when ever i click the setoninfowindow i only get the first.class in the new screen. say if i click one of the marker it has to go to first.class and if i click on another marker it has to go to the second.class

**firstloop**

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> data : firstLoop) {
    final String regno =    (String) data.get(REG_NO);              
    String dname =  (String) data.get(CAR);
    final String driver_ph =    (String) data.get(MOBILE);
    longt=Float.parseFloat((String) data.get(LONGITUDE));
    lat=Float.parseFloat((String) data.get(LATITUDE));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(lat, longt))
   .title("title2")
   .snippet(name)
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
   .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_car)));
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {                      
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),second.class);
    startActivity(in);
    }});      }
```

**secondloop**

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> data : secondloop) {
    String reg =    (String) data.get(ID);
    longt=Float.parseFloat((String) data.get(1_LONGITUDE));
    lat=Float.parseFloat((String) data.get(1_LATITUDE));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, longt))
    .title("title1")
    .snippet(reg)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_car)));
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),first.class);
    in.putExtra("driverid", marker.getSnippet());
    startActivity(in);  }});          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener` in a loop. It overrides any listener you set previously.

Instead set it once just after you retrieve reference to `GoogleMap` and distinguish marker inside `onInfoWindowClick`.

Comment: @sup `if (marker.getTitle().equals("title1")) { /* start first activity */ } else { /* start second activity */ }`